# Spark Streaming - using foreachPartition and saveToCassandra for better parallelization

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

Below code is working fine but it takes time to write to cassandra when we have huge inflow of transactions.

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
val parsedStream = stream.map(_._2).map(EmpParser.parse(_)).cache()
```

Below code is writing to cassandra in sequential and executes in one executor.

```
parsedStream.saveToCassandra("test", "ct_table", SomeColumns("emp_id","emp_name","emp_sal","emp_dept"))
```

But i wanted to parallelize the write to cassandra by doing foreachPartition. But I don't see saveToCassandra option at foreachPartition.

```
parsedStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partition =>
      partition.saveToCassandra("test", "ct_table", SomeColumns("emp_id","emp_name","emp_sal","emp_dept"))
    }
}
```

Any way we can achieve this ?

Comment: `saveToCassandra` is defined on the `RDD`/`DStream` level, while `partition` is a simple scala `Iterator`, hence you don't see it defined.

Comment: OK. Any idea how could we achieve writing to cassandra in parallel executions by all of my executors ?

Comment: you could do` parseStream.repartition(num).saveToCassandra`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using direct stream, there're two ways to increase parallelism.

1. Increase the number of Kafka partitions. When using direct stream, Spark automatically creates as many partition as Kafka. However, depending on your setup, this might not be feasible.
2. Using Spark's `repartition`. In most case, it's better to `repartition` on the input rather than the output.

   ```
   val num: Int = ? // Number of partitition
   val parsedStream = stream.repartition(num).map(_._2).map(EmpParser.parse(_))
   parsedStream.saveToCassandra(...)
   ```

If you only need to use `parsedStream` once, it's not necessary to cache it.

Comment: I've a requirement to write the same data to elastic search also.  parsedStream.saveToCassandra("test", "ct_table", SomeColumns("emp_id","emp_name","emp_sal","emp_dept"))
currently i am saving to elastic as below. please suggest parrlelized approach to save to ElasticSearch. parsedStream.foreachRDD(rdd => { rdd.saveToEs("test/emp") })

Comment: When my code is writing to both cassandra and elasticsearch, the processing time is increasing to 3 seconds (that depends on the data size). But if i try to write only to cassandra, then the processing time comes down to 0.3 to 0.7 seconds.